# quick sort (lomuto's partitioning) implementation

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement lomuto's partitioning quicksort but I couldn't catch why this is not working.Thank you guys

```js
const quickSort = (arr) => {
    return quickSortHelper(arr, 0, arr.length-1)
}
const quickSortHelper = (arr, start, end) => {
    if (start >= end) return ;
    let midIdx = Math.floor(start+end/2);
    [arr[start], arr[midIdx]] = [arr[midIdx], arr[start]];
    let pivot = arr[start];
    let smaller = start;
    // let bigger = start;
    for (let bigger= start+1; bigger<arr.length; bigger++) {
        if (pivot > arr[bigger]) {
            smaller++;
            [arr[smaller], arr[bigger]] = [arr[bigger], arr[smaller]];
        }
    }
    [arr[start], arr[smaller]] = [arr[smaller], arr[start]];
    quickSortHelper(arr, start, smaller-1)    
    quickSortHelper(arr, smaller+1, end)
    return arr;
}

console.log(quickSort([3,9,7,7,1,4,2,1,5]))
```

Comment: shouldn't `midIdx` be somewhere between `start`and `end`?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: try `console.log(start, midIdx, end, start <= midIdx && midIdx <= end);` like it's sorting the range `6-7` and the mid is `4`

Comment: okay. I edit the midIdx value to start+end/2 but still not sorted. :(